# Tensor Product of Vector Bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

In [Hatcher's book on Vector Bundles](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) he states (page 14) that

> It is routine to verify that the tensor product operation for vector bundles over a
>   fixed base space is commutative, associative, and has an identity element, the trivial
>   line bundle. It is also distributive with respect to direct sum.

The gluing functions for the bundle $E_1 \otimes E_2$ are the tensor product of the two matricies $g^1_{\beta \alpha}(x)$ and $g^2_{\beta \alpha}(x)$

So for the tensor product for vector bundles to be commutative, wouldn't we require that $g^1_{\beta \alpha}(x) \otimes g^2_{\beta \alpha}(x) = g^2_{\beta \alpha}(x) \otimes g^1_{\beta \alpha}(x)$?

This is certainly not true - the best we can say is that they are [permutation equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Bilinearity_and_associativity)

(Since $g_{\beta \alpha}(x):U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The desired statement about tensor products is that $E_1 \otimes E_2$ is *isomorphic* to $E_2 \otimes E_1$, not that it is *equal* to $E_2 \otimes E_1$.

If $E'$ and $E''$ are vector bundles given by transition functions $g'_{ij}$ and $g''_{ij}$, then they will be isomorphic iff these transition functions determine the same element in the (sheaf) cohomology set $H^1(X,\operatorname{GL}_n)$.  This means two things: (i) one is allowed to pass to a refinement of the covering, and (ii) one regards two sets of transition functions on the same covering as being equivalent if there exists 
$\lambda_i: X \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n$ such that

$g''_{ij} = \lambda_i^{-1} g'_{ij} \lambda_j$:

one says that $g'$ and $g''$ are **cohomologous**.

This is all rather abstract, but if you look back at what you've already written, you should find that you've explained exactly what functions $\lambda_i$ to take to show that your two sets of transition functions are cohomologous (in this case it is not necessary to refine the cover), hence the corresponding vector bundles are isomorphic.

**Added**: I just looked at Hatcher's notes/prebook, and he does not introduce the cohomological perspective here.  So probably there's a better way to look at it.  How about this: one can argue Atiyah-style (i.e., from his book on K-theory) that there is a **natural** isomorphism of finite dimensional vector spaces $V \otimes W \rightarrow W \otimes V$ (just switch the factors!), so this will extend to an isomorphism of the tensor product of vector bundles.  (This seems a lot simpler, but the OP phrased things in terms of transition functions, and I like that perspective a lot.  It requires nonabelian sheaf cohomology to really be done right, but -- what can I say? -- in my line of work nonabelian cohomology of sheaves -- on Grothendieck topologies, no less -- is fairly ubiquitous anyway.)

Comment: Hi! Could you explain the sheaf cohomology in more detail? I certainly know the material but I am not familiar with the terminology. Glad to know what you had written.

Comment: @user7887: I'm afraid it would take me too long to expose the connection between fiber bundles and sheaf cohomology in detail.  I'll tell you where I learned it from: $\S 1.3$ of Hirzebruch's *Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry*.  I recommend it highly.

Comment: thanks for that, I had suspected it was something like this. I agree if you use Atiyah's 'continuous functor $T$' that is is clear, but I was trying to prove what Hatcher says. Maybe we have different definitions of routine! (Or perhaps he was referring to using the construction on the fibers - $h_1 \otimes h_2:p^{-1}_1(U) \otimes p^{-1}_2(U) \to U \times (\mathbb{R}^{n_1} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{n_2})$ and then use the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{n_1} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{n_2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n_2} \otimes \mathbb{R}^{n_1})$

Comment: L.Clark: Thank you greatly for the reference.

Comment: As a minor comment, there is a bit more than "naturality of the isomorphism": namely, under the tensor product, vector bundles form a symmetric monoidal category (which includes various coherence axioms for these various isomorphisms).